# What does asm standard for?

Tags: java, jar

Sometimes I see the letters "`asm`" in the name file library jar.

For example, in the packages framework library.

```
SpringFramework  :  org.springframework.asm-x.y.z.M(a).jar 
Eclipse Link     :  org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar
```

`Asm`, what does it mean?

Comment: [AMS Home Page](http://asm.ow2.org/)

Comment: The goal of the ASM library is to generate, transform and analyze compiled Java classes, represented as byte arrays (as they are stored on disk and loaded in the Java Virtual Machine)
Src-[ASM 4.0 A Java bytecode engineering library](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf).

Comment: The ASM name does not mean anything: it is just a reference to the ---asm---(_ underscore) keyword in C, which allows some functions to be implemented in assembly language.

Source: [1.2.1. Scope - footnote](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf)

Answer (score 9):

Both the libraries you mention are copies of the [ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/), which provides low-level bytecode manipulation capabilities (ASM -> assembly).

Spring and EclipseLink change the package names of ASM and repackage it for their internal use.  This is to avoid conflicts in case a user of these libraries wants to use their own version of ASM.  By having the renamed packages, both versions can happily coexist.  The JDK does this as well - you can see that jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifier for example is part of the JDK.  The 'jdk.internal' prefix is to avoid conflicts with other versions of ASM users might want to use.

Answer (score 7):

> The ASM name does not mean anything: it is just a reference to the `__asm__` keyword in C, which allows some functions to be implemented in assembly language.
>
> The goal of the ASM library is to generate, transform and analyze compiled
>   Java classes, represented as byte arrays (as they are stored on disk and loaded
>   in the Java Virtual Machine). For this purpose ASM provides tools to read,
>   write and transform such byte arrays by using higher level concepts than bytes,
>   such as numeric constants, strings, Java identifiers, Java types, Java class
>   structure elements, etc. Note that the scope of the ASM library is strictly
>   limited to reading, writing, transforming and analyzing classes. In particular
>   the class loading process is out of scope.

Source: [1.2.1. Scope - footnote](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

ASM is the bytecode framework for Java which has the most efficient performance.

ASM is used by cobertura for code coverage, and by hibernate and AOP for generating proxy classes.

There are lots of other API which internally use ASM for playing with the java bytecode (as mentioned in your question).

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjectWeb_ASM

Answer (score 0):

ASM simply stands for **ASMifier tool**

Comment: I tried searching with keywords [ASMifier class](https://www.google.com.vn/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=wKJ1VJPsOOSK8QeBjoGAAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=ASMifier+class), but no more results related.

Comment: __asm__ in C is related to Assembly, ASM is although not related to it. But it usually means assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a reference to Assembly (Language), since if we consider bytecode to be Java's machine code, then a library like that would be somewhat similar to an Asm compiler in the x86 world (i.e. allowing you to write the machine/bytecode in an easier way).